# Need to make changes to repository structure

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I need to log in to a clearcase repository via command line and make some basic changes.

Do I need to use cleartool for this, or can I log in via putty ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[`cleartool`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/c_hood_cleartool_cli.htm)** is your best approach, provided that you are using the full ClearCase client (instead of [CCRC](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21205629), which [uses a different CLI](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021929)).

Don't forget you don't have to open a cleartool session.
You can type several cleartool commands, each in their own cleartool session.

So to access a ClearCase repository (a Vob, within a view), you need to:

- start the view: `cleartool startview myView`
- go to the vob within the view (no need for cleartool for that): `cd /path/to/your/view/vob`
- make your changes

---

Now if you had to actually connect to the Vob server, and do some administration changes, then yes, putty would be a way to do that. But you would still execute some cleartool command once connected to the server.